# Syntax: Comparisons in python

Tags: python, syntax, comparison

I'm new to python and am having trouble comparing two elements.  One element is from an array that I created using the readlines() method on a text file, and the other is just a variable I assigned a value.  I have code that looks something like

```
f=open('graph.txt')
graph=f.readlines()
f.close()

node=0


print graph[0][0]
print node
print graph[0][0]==node
```

and it prints

```
0
0
False
```

Why is the double equals giving a false, when the two items print the same value?  Is it because they are different types, or something like that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing strings and integers. Convert one or the other:

```
graph[0][0] == str(node)
```

or

```
int(graph[0][0]) == node
```

or make `node` a string to begin with:

```
node = '0'
```

Note that `'0'` and `0` (string and integer values) print the same:

```
>>> print '0'
0
>>> print 0
0
```

Use `repr()` to make the difference clear:

```
>>> print repr('0')
'0'
>>> print repr(0)
0
```